# Symfony 2.7 Uploading file

Tags: mysql, symfony, ubuntu

i'm developing a website using Symfony 2.7! i've just started learning it, am trying to upload file, the file name is saved in my database but it's not uploaded in directory 
Can any one help me here is My Controller and Entity :
Controller :

```
namespace institutionBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use institutionBundle\Entity\Classe;
use institutionBundle\Form\ClasseType;
use institutionBundle\Entity\Niveau;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface as Container;
/**
 * Classe controller.
 *
 */
class ClasseController extends Controller
{
    public function newAction(request $request,$institut)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $classe = new Classe();
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($classe)
            ->add('nom','text',array('required'=>true,'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Entrez le nom')))

            ->add('niveau', 'entity', array(
                'attr'=>array('class'=>'form-control'),
                'class' => 'institutionBundle:Niveau',
                'property' => 'nom',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er)use ($institut) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                        ->andWhere('i.institut = :niv')->setParameter('niv', $institut);
                }

            ))
           ->add('file')
           ->add('Ajouter','submit',array('attr'=>array('class'=>'btn btn-success of')))

            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $alert='';
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $x = $form->get('nom')->getData();


            $d = $em->createQuery("select d from institutionBundle:Classe d where (d.nom = :niv and d.institut = :inst )")
                ->setParameters(array('niv'=>$x,'inst'=>$institut))
                ->getResult();
                $num2 = count($d);
                if($num2>0){
                    $alert ='Cette Classe existe déjà!  Veuillez choisir un autre nom';

                }else{
                    $inst = $em->getRepository("institutionBundle:Institut")->find($institut);
                    $classe->upload();
                    $classe->setInstitut($inst);
                    $mats=$form->get('niveau')->getData();
                    foreach ($mats as $mat) {
                        $s = $em->getRepository("institutionBundle:Niveau")->find($mat);
                        $classe->setNiveau($s);
                    }
                    $em-> persist($classe);
                    $em->flush();

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('home_classes',array('institut'=>$institut));
                }
        }

        return $this->render('institutionBundle:Classe:new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),'alert'=>$alert,'institut'=>$institut
        ));
    }

}
```

Entity :

```
 <?php

    namespace institutionBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    /**
     * Classe
     *
     * @ORM\Table()
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Classe
    {
        /**
         * @var integer
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $nom;



        /**
         *
         * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="institutionBundle\Entity\Niveau",inversedBy="id")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="niveau",referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $niveau;

        /**
         *
         *             @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="institutionBundle\Entity\Institut",inversedBy="id")
         * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="institut",referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $institut;


        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;

        /**
         * Sets file.
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         */
        public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        /**
         * Get file.
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getFile()
        {
            return $this->file;
        }

         /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        public $path;


        public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        public function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads';
        }
        public function upload()
        {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
        );

        $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
        }

        /**
         * Set path
         *
         * @param string $path
         *
         * @return Stage
         */
        public function setPath($path)
        {
            $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            return $this->path;
        }

        /**
         * Set matiere
         *
         * @param string $institut
         * @return Professeur
         */
        public function setInstitut($inst)
        {
            $this->institut = $inst;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }

        /**
         * Set nom
         *
         * @param string $nom
         * @return Classe
         */
        public function setNom($nom)
        {
            $this->nom = $nom;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get nom
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getNom()
        {
            return $this->nom;
        }

        /**
         * Get dateProchain
         *
         * @return \DateTime 
         */
        public function getNiveau()
        {
            return $this->niveau;
        }
        /**
         * Set dateProchain
         *
         * @param \DateTime $dateProchain
         * @return Eleve
         */
        public function setNiveau($niveau)
        {
            $this->niveau = $niveau;

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found the solution

```
protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you are missing the Uploader service.
Or maybe you didn't post it on your question.

This should help you:
[Symfony 2.7 Uploader Service](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/upload_file.html#creating-an-uploader-service)

The code there is quite similar to yours so it should be easy to understand and translate to your problem